# No Errors yet nothing in Console?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

Just after some help with some code i've written to extract data using `HttpClient`.

I am new to writing code so can't find my problem. Could someone pls help me troubleshoot this.

I expect to write the data of the table i'm **scraping** to the console line.

**Any help appreciated**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace weatherCheck
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetHtmlAsync();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        
        protected static async void GetHtmlAsync()
        {
            var url = "https://www.weatherzone.com.au/vic/melbourne/melbourne";

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

            var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);



            //grab the rain chance, rain in mm and date

            var MyTable = Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("table")
            .Where(table => table.Attributes.Contains("id"))
, table => table.Attributes["id"].Value == "forecast-table");

            List<HtmlNode> rows = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr").ToList();

            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (MyTable != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(MyTable.GetAttributeValue("forecast-table", " "));

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your application? For example what does the ` var MyTable = Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` line actually return, do you know? Also you should have async methods returning false, if you don't want to return anything return Task so that they can be awaited

Comment: How do  you know there are no exceptions?  Your `catch` block is empty so you are ignoring anything that might occur!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your code to look up the values but it didnt produce anything for me either. When i look at the `htmlDocument.DocumentNode.OuterHtml` to view the entire Html it is scraping, I dont see anything in the document that reflects an attribute `forecast-table`.

Also, you are validating MyTable each time you loop through rows. You should validate `row != null` along with printing attribute from `row`.

```
var MyTable = Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("table")
    .Where(table => table.Attributes.Contains("id")), table => table.Attributes["id"].Value == "forecast-table");

    List<HtmlNode> rows = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr").ToList();

    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        try
        {
            if (row != null) // Here, it should be row, not My Table along with MyTable in line below.
                Console.WriteLine(row.GetAttributeValue("forecast-table", " "));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

**Problem is**

You also should know that Html you view by using Dev Tools on chrome is not the same as the one you see in HtmlAgilityPack. Chrome renders the page after executing the scripts where HtmlAgilityPack simply provides you with default HTML of the page. This is the reason why you are not able to get the value of forecast-table.

Comment: Thank you.

When i check out text i see the id of forecast tablw in outerHtml.

Comment: One warning: SelectNodes returns null instead of an empty list when nothing was found

Answer (score 0):

From [Doc](https://docs.workflowgen.com/wfgmy/v400/html/694a309a-0e10-37d4-2733-55589302bd13.htm), For `GetAttributeValue(name,def)` it'll return def if the attribute not found.

So, it'll print ""(empty string if the attribute not found in your case)

remove `async` and `await` as you already calling `httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);`

```
var html =httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);
```

And print,

```
 Console.WriteLine(MyTable.GetAttributeValue("forecast-table","SOME_TEXT_HERE").ToString());
```